# Should I preserve spelling when quoting American English in a British English text, or vice versa?

Tags: orthography, quoting

Suppose I am writing an (academic) text in British English, but have to quote a text from an author who writes in American English.

Should I preserve the author's original spelling, or convert it to my text's spelling standards?

*This question is intended to be closed as a duplicate of [When quoting a speaker of another English dialect, should you spell things his way?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89571/when-quoting-speakers-of-another-english-dialect-than-your-own-should-you-spell) to improve Google visibility. (I did not manage to find that question through Google during my initial search, even though it is one of the best resources on the topic. This question supplies key words which the original doesn't have.)*

Comment: I don't know that we do a lot of SEO on this site.  You'd be better off suggesting an edit to the original post to add a few google keywords.  We should post this in meta.

Comment: Please see http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4592/59527.  I have posted this question on Meta.

Comment: @David I see your point, but the official reason why questions closed as duplicate are kept around is SEO. Had I posted this without the notice, it would not have been a problem. But let's take it to Meta, cool

Comment: I understand what you mean, too.  But, it likely would have been closed as a dupe regardless.  Let's see what everyone suggests.  I personally would lean toward beefing up the keywords in the original.

Comment: `But, it likely would have been closed as a dupe regardless.` -> exactly. That's my point -  the only difference between a normal dupe and this question was that I stated my intention. (But yeah, let's see what the community says)

Comment: I've changed my mind about editing the original.  But, see my post in meta.

Comment: If it's inside quote marks, it's exactly what was written, including spelling. If it was quoted from speech, you're on your own, since it wasn't spelled to start with.

Comment: This question is about **text**, the other question is about **speech** and so is not a duplicate of this.